# Insert "javascript:void(0);" into URL

Tags: javascript, urls, html, links

I am no beginner Wordpress developer by any means but I am completely stuck with this. I have tried an array of alternatives without any result (href="#", href="#void", etc.).

I need "javascript:void(0);" as the href attribute in a HTML link. Inserting this in the text editor, flicking to the visual then back to the text editor makes it disappear.

I have read up some information on it (re: esc_url) but can't seem to find a fix. Is there a way for me to make this work on a Page in Wordpress somehow by way of a function or script?

The link I am trying to generate is:
`<a href="javascript:void(0);"> subscribe </a>`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain why do you need this. There are too many ways to achieve the goal: a plugin, `data-*` attribute and jQuery, hardcoding in the template upon some condition, custom field, disabling content filtering (very bad idea) and many more.

Comment: I agree with Max, this shouldn't be necessary. This answer from SO is a good explanation of why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293130

Comment: Thanks peeps. I tried the link without the href in it and it actually worked  fine. I can't believe I wrecked my head over this. 

Answer (score 1):

I also can't stand the fact the Wordpress removes "javascript:void(0);" from my hrefs (or anything else TBH...) upon saving or using the visual editor.

I just started using the [Raw HTML plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/raw-html/) that does the job. I enclosed my code in [raw] ... [/raw] codes, and did NOT use the visual editor. My "voids" remain now! :)

Answer (score 0):

we use `javascript:void(0);` to prevent the default operation of page and link it to the click or other js action.
So the workaround for removal of `javacript:void(0);` for me was to use `#` in the `href` and then use `e.preventDefault();` in the js action.